# How to solve Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect http to https when someone hit the url http://www.makememyvideo.com/dev/fr/project/9/1.php , so it should be https://www.makememyvideo.com/dev/fr/project/9/1.php .

I am using htaccess redirect method like this , the htaccess file is in the folder 9

```
   Options -Multiviews
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   #RewriteBase  /fr/project/9

     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.makememyvideo.com/dev/project/fr/9/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /fr/project/9/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule (.*)/$ /fr/project/9/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /fr/project/9/$0/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

But it is giving a redirect loop error, also i have htaccess files in the folder project and in the document root.

Any help will be appreciated a lot

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule - https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi this is  not converting http to https and not also giving any error

Answer (score 0):

This is working on my site

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.xxxxxx.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```